# Module Management in python with test

Tags: python, file, module

I'm currently working on a project that has following file structure:

- Modules

  - Device 1
  - Device 2
- Tests

  - Test 1

Ultimately, I wan't to be able to import `Device 1` and `Device 2` in my test case `Test 1`. This is currently achieved by adding the parent directory to the path: `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))`. Unfortunately, this prevents my IDE from showing me useful information for the devices. Relative imports don't seem to work here since `Test 1` is the main file, i.e. it is started with `python test1.py`. I'm using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in a way that I'm not 100% is standard, but it's working for the meantime:
[image: Screenshot of sample project]

So, as you can see, I don't have a `main.py` in this mock-up, yet. What I do have are modules in one folder and tests in the other.

The main "trick" (and, again, I'm not sure it's advisable) is to climb down the folder hierarchy using `sys.path.append` and `__file__.rsplit('\',2)`. The other trick is that, if called as main, every module loads up the init and tests itself, but if the init file is called, it tests *all* of the modules.

Hopefully someone can show you a better solution, but this may work in a pinch.

Comment: thanks for your input. As a side note, my tests are no unit tests, i.e. all of the tests will run like `python testX.py` I'm still waiting for a more elegant solution. An obvious solution would to move the tests one level up, but I'm not sure if my team agrees on this.